# Why is onclick not working in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, eventhandler

I wrote a simple code to learn Eventhandling in JavaScript but when I click on the button "Click" the function hello() does not work, why?

`html file:`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="hello.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button id="click">Click</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

`JavaScript file:`

```
    document.getElementById("click").onclick = hello;
    function hello() {
      alert("You Clicked!");
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling the script before the dom is generated. experiment to call the  right before the   tag.